# Keeping the row which has "suv", otherwise keep the other ones

Tags: r

For example consider the default **mpg** dataframe.

I can find out what unique classes a car manufacturer has using:

```
mpg %>% distinct(manufacturer, class)

# A tibble: 32 x 2
   manufacturer class  
   <chr>        <chr>  
 1 audi         compact
 2 audi         midsize
 3 chevrolet    suv    
 4 chevrolet    2seater
 5 chevrolet    midsize
 6 dodge        minivan
 7 dodge        pickup 
 8 dodge        suv    
 9 ford         suv    
10 ford         pickup
```

Now actually what I want is that if a manufacturer has **suv** in class then only keep that row, and if it doesn't then keep all the other rows showing other classes.

Also, coming from excel I am using 'remove duplicate' trick here, where you can basically sort and then remove duplicates. Pretty sure there will be a better & smarter way then using **distinct** in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can select only `'suv'` rows if that `class` is present in `manufacturer` or select all the rows of the `manufacturer`.

```
library(dplyr)

mpg %>% 
  distinct(manufacturer, class) %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>%
  filter(if(any(class == 'suv')) class == 'suv' else TRUE)

#  manufacturer class     
#   <chr>        <chr>     
# 1 audi         compact   
# 2 audi         midsize   
# 3 chevrolet    suv       
# 4 dodge        suv       
# 5 ford         suv       
# 6 honda        subcompact
# 7 hyundai      midsize   
# 8 hyundai      subcompact
# 9 jeep         suv       
#10 land rover   suv       
#11 lincoln      suv       
#12 mercury      suv       
#13 nissan       suv       
#14 pontiac      midsize   
#15 subaru       suv       
#16 toyota       suv       
#17 volkswagen   compact   
#18 volkswagen   subcompact
#19 volkswagen   midsize
```

Comment: Alternative: `filter(xor(!any(class == "suv"), class == "suv"))`

Comment: Idiomatically I'd prefer if it were `%xor%` to match `&` and `|` ... in its prefix-functional form, it looks like it should be grouped with Excel's `=and(...)` and `=or(...)` (it is, in fact ... `=xor(...)`).